# Can I make a shell context action run as administrator?

Tags: windows-7, shell, administrator, context-menu, privileges

I like to add a shell context menu for registering .dll files using the command

```
%windir%Microsoft/Framework/v2.0.50727/regasm.exe "%1" /codebase
```

which used to work fine in XP.  However in Windows 7 this command requires administrator privileges.  Is there some way I can make this command run as administrator?

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the GUI?  Are you having to do this often for some reason?  Why don't you just open a CMD prompt as admin and so it from there?

Comment: yes I have to do it often, as I switch from building source code from one branch to the other and need to register various files, and I don't want to have the hassle of opening a cmd prompt navigating to the folder for the regasm command and then typing the full path of the file to register, which can be long

Comment: Why not use the hidden Administrator account when doing this kind of work. cmd...net user administrator /active:yes...log off and you can now log into the real admin account.

Comment: @Moab,  I'm and administrator on the machine already.  And logging on and off seems like a hassle to do this.

Comment: In windows7 user accounts are not like the hidden Admin account, so you are not really the true admin while in a user account like you were in XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you need this command to launch using the Shell verb "runas".

You can download a reg file here.

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/register-dlls-elevated-using-the-context-menu/

```
REGEDIT4

;Register modules (Elevated) from the context menu
;March 25, 2008 - (c) 2008 Ramesh Srinivasan
;http://www.winhelponline.com
;http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dllfile\shell]
@="none"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dllfile\shell\runas]
@="&Register (as Administrator)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dllfile\shell\runas\command]
@="regsvr32.exe \"%1\""


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ocxfile\shell]
@="none"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ocxfile\shell\runas]
@="&Register (as Administrator)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ocxfile\shell\runas\command]
@="regsvr32.exe \"%1\""
```

Comment: How do I add multiple verbs that need to run as administrator?

Comment: @Doub use cascading context menus. Inside you can put many runas'!